# Is there a way to refer to a class you are going to instantiate?

Tags: oop, naming-conventions

Is there a term instead of always saying the class with/out the main method or the instantiated class or other clumsy things like that?

Comment: What does a "main" method have to do with instantiation?

Comment: I'd guess you need to name and conquer: Give the thing you are referring to all the time a name, like *o*, *a* or something such. Then use that name in your text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the term *candidate object*.

Answer (score 0):

An instance of a class is an object.

Comment: I was more looking for a name to call a class your going to create an object from.

Comment: @Adam: then you're talking about a Factory.